# What is the animation effect that iOS mailing app is using?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm trying to create an APP prototype and I was wondering what is the name of animation/transition effect that you see on top of the mailing app when you click the new message button. It's animation effect where the navigation bar does not fully go to the top of the screen and you can the previous view in the background? And is there way to add that animation effect to my storyboard? If not, is there a easily available library that will

Comment: Have u tried to play with the `UIWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that is a custom transition for which apple does not provide api.